# How do I copy html div like mouse select and copy then paste it anywhere. In angular 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, angular2-routing, angular8

I tried...

```
    const selBox = document.createElement('textarea');
    const selBox1 = (selBox);
    selBox1.style.position = 'fixed';
    selBox1.style.left = '0';
    selBox1.style.top = '0';
    selBox1.style.opacity = '0';
    selBox1.value = val;
    document.body.appendChild(selBox);
    selBox1.focus();
    selBox1.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(selBox)
```

But it only copy the inner text value only. 
And I want to full div with same CSS property. For pasting it on the mail or another place.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/547773/how-do-i-copy-paste-website-content-with-formatting , Check the post

Comment: Sorry @AkhilAravind , I this is not my solution. I want to copy whole div element inner content as it is. and paste it to email.

Comment: I know its not your solution, but the post says you cannot do that unless you are using an editor. Thats what it says.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found a code to resolve my issue. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```js
CopyFunction=()=> {
  const elm = document.getElementById("copyCodeId");
  // for Internet Explorer

  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    const range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(elm);
    range.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied div content to clipboard");
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    // other browsers

    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elm);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied div content to clipboard");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="code-bg" id="copyCodeId">
  Click on the button to copy the text from the div element. Try to paste the text<span style="color:red"> (e.g. ctrl+v)</span> afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.
</div>
<button onclick="CopyFunction()">Copy div</button>
```

Comment: Does this solution copy css styles also ??

Comment: Yes, @AkhilAravind . The best solution for copy-paste HTML content into any clipboard or anywhere.

Comment: your solution will work, i accept that. But my concern is 'DOES IT COPY THE CSS PROPERY ALSO'. Like color, font size, etc

Comment: Yes, It copies all CSS like fonts, colors, background etc...  :-)

Comment: Now run the snippet, copy and past it in the comment, does the text shows in red color ?? unless you are using an editor ??

Comment: Thanks @AkhilAravind. I am just trying to resolve my issue. Actually I want to copy and paste on email. This is my requirement. And this code fulfill my need. Thanks for editing and snippet.